# rails4 form checkbox is giving issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

Hi I want to show a checkbox in which if value is true then itshows unchecked and if value is false then it shows checked. I am having is_active field as boolean which accepts 0 or1 . So if employee is_active = 1 then my checkbox must show unchecked if value is 0 then it show checked. How to do this am not getting it. I have written like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_active %>
```

so for this if its 1 then shows checked which I dont want. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this I hope this will help you.

```
## Please replace your @employee object with your object.

<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true) }) %>
```

and if you wanted to update the object with reverse way please see the following code, i.e. if you will checked it it will update it with 0 and if you unchecked it will update it with 1.

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {checked: (@employee.is_active ? false : true) }, 0, 1) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
<%= f.check_box(:is_active, {}, 0, 1) %>
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

try ternary operator to check true/false and then check/uncheck

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="<%= f.is_active ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'%>" />
```

Comment: Raw HTML is not recommended in Rails. Good to have some rails way.

Comment: @RAJ its not recommended...can be used based on few scenarios sometimes.at the end every code get converted to html.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify check/uncheck values as:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_active, {}, "0", "1" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.check_box :is_active, {}, "true", "false" %>
```

this should work fine.....